# Is there a way to make a PR but have the repo private in my github account?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-fork

I want to contribute to a public repo with a pull request.

I can't seem to find a workaround for it, when I fork the public repo it shows up in my account as well.

However, I don't want that repo to be seen in my github account.

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Answer (score 6):

To issue a PR on a public repository your fork must also be public. The repo you are issuing the pull request to must be able to access and view your fork. The PR will be public. If accepted, your commits will appear in the public repository.

> However, I don't want that repo to be seen in my github account.

Since your fork must be public, the question is why do you not want the fork to be seen on your account? [There's probably a better way to accomplish your unstated goal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Depending on why, I can think of a few work arounds.

1. Delete your fork after the PR is accepted. This is the simplest thing to do.
2. Make another Github account with a different email address just for this PR.

Note that in both cases, the PR and your commits will still be visible in the repo you contributed to.

Comment: Thankyou! The repo I'm contributing to is really not that awesome and mine is a very small change to add. Didn't want my friends to see my useless contribution.

Comment: @Parzival Oh pish posh. Every contribution is appreciated. And let me tell you after taking contributions for 20 years, *especially* the small ones because it lets others <strike>be sloppy</strike> focus on big things. Taking the time to, for example, fix typos in the documentation is very useful.

Answer (score 6):

Simple answer: **No**.
Github does not allow you to do that.
For more information, you can go to `Settings` of your repo, you will check that it is mentioned clearly inside Danger Zone area.

> You cannot change the visibility of a fork. [Please duplicate the
> repository](https://docs.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since September 2022, you can [make your GitHub profile private](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/customizing-your-profile/setting-your-profile-to-private).

It won't prevent the forked repository from appearing on your profile, but at least your followers won't be notified. And you can delete this fork as soon as you've submitted your PR.